# RAC, data guard, physical stand by and impdp

Tags: rac, impdp, dataguard

We're setting up a RAC 2 nodes data guard 11g environment, with a remote physical standby (2 nodes also)

We receive the client's data he exports with expdp. We have imported his dump in the primary database a first time for our tests. The day we go to production we will have to import it again. We will probably have to drop the data before doing so, so will we have to disconnect the data guard environment before we proceed? What advice would you give me in this context?

Thank you,

S.

Comment: RAC and DataGuard are two different things. What exactly are you using?

Comment: We are setting up a MAA dataguard configuration on 2 different Oracle ODA, as explained in this document http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/maa-wp-10g-racprimaryracphysicalsta-131940.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop user on primary then this will be also reflected on secondary site. Also impdp will work as expected. But when you are about to import large amount of data MAA might slow down the whole procedure significantly.

If you have enough experience with RMAN you might try:

- shutdown and disconnect the secondary
- import data into master
- backup master using RMAN
- cross-site-restore RMAN backup of primary on secondary node, thus re-initialize the secondary.

Although this approach might seem to be complicated it might be faster in large configurations.

Comment: Thank you, I really needed a confirmation that dropping users and impdp would reflect to the standby database.

Comment: It should work like that. At least for user not having DBA privs. For users having password in `orapw` file it might work differently.

Comment: Do you think the slowdown would be that consequent even though standby and primary are on 2 different servers?

Comment: Yes. Especially when standby is located in some distant location. For every write onto local disk (redo) you also have to wait till data are sent over the network, then written on standby and acknowledge is sent back to primary. For large deployments this might case 30-50% slowdown. If you are about to load a lot of data, maybe you should set protection mode to max performance before the load.